# How do I implement a remove/delete function for a Patricia Trie?

Tags: patricia-trie

I have partially implemented a Patricia Trie, it's still not complete since it lacks a **delete/remove** function which is used to remove nodes from the Trie, I have found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/PatriciaTrieTemplateClass.aspx) describing the structure, which comes with an implementation in C++, there's a remove/delete function, but I can't figure out what's the idea behind the implementation.

How do I remove a node from the Trie and leave the Trie in a proper state?

Comment: Sorry for not having noticed your comment, I just started to use SO. I was trying to implement the structure in Java and C++, well, it can be any language, I only need to know the idea behind the implementation, not the implementation itself. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a PATRICIA in C recently.  In order to remove a node, find the down-trie node which points backward up the trie to the victim (this may be the victim node itself.)

Once found, if the victim node is NOT the backward-referer, switch the victim with its referer.  This puts the victim close to being a "leaf" node, and its backward reference will be to itself.  The removal is very simple, then.